# Regex to get parts of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

all i am struggling to get sections of a string with regex without using Split or any other similar function here is my scenario:

I have this text `U:BCCNT.3;GO`which i want to get the different sections divided but the symbols in the middle I have managed to get the first one with this regex `/(.+):/.exec(value)` this gives me the first word till the colon(:) and these are the different variations of the value

**Second section `BCCNT`**

`BCCNT.3;GO` -> without the `U:` so the string might also contain no colon so for the second section the logic would be `any text that is between : and . or any text ending with . and nothing infront`

**Third section `.3`**-> `any text starting with a . and ending with nothing or anytext staring with a . and ending with a ; semicolon`

**Fourth section `;GO`**-> `any text starting with a ; and ending with nothing`

**EDIT**
and preferably on separate variables like

```
const sectionOne = regex.exec(value);
const sectionTwo = regex.exec(value);
const sectionThree = regex.exec(value);
const sectionFour = regex.exec(value);
```

and which ever value doesnt match the pattern the variable would just be `undefined` or null or any empty string

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex approach using 4 separate optional capture groups for each possible component:

```js
var input = "U:BCCNT.3;GO";
var re = /^([^:]+:)?([^.]+)?(\.[^;]+)?(;.*)?$/g;
var m;

m = re.exec(input);
if (m) {
    console.log(m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4]);
}
```

Comment: Okay this seems about right but if my input is this for example 
`var input = "U:BCCNT;GO";` i get 
`m[1]=U:
m[2]=BCCNT;GO->should be only BCCNT
m[3]=undefined->correct because we dont have .3
m[4]=undefined->should have been ;GO`

Comment: You may need some other logic in addition to regex.  If a regex group doesn't match it won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```js
/^(?:([^:]*):)?([^.]*)\.(?:([^;]*);(.*))?/
```

For example:

```js
const s = 'U:BCCNT.3;GO';
const m = s.match(/^(?:([^:]*):)?([^.]*)\.(?:([^;]*);(.*))?/);

console.log(m);
```

Comment: @Surafel Now you're tacking on extras. My answer is for the original question. I have to step away from the computer now, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, which one is the separator from this regex maybe i can separte them myself /^(?:([^:]*):)?([^.]*)\.(?:([^;]*);(.*))?/